# Best practices for forwarding collections

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

I am looking for best practices to create forwarding collections like the in Google [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingList.java): 
For example a ForwardingList in Scala would look like:

```
   trait ForwardingList[T] 
   {
      def delegate: List
   }
```

However it is not clear to me which traits this list should extend and which methods have to be overridden as there are many candidates

- `List[T]`
- `ListLike[T, ForwardingList[T]]`
- `ListLike[T, List[T]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `Proxy` which requires you to define just `val self: <Collection>`. Be careful, however, as these `Proxy` classes return the collection for that proxy, i.e. `SeqProxy` returns a `Seq` on `filter`, `map`, etc.

The `ProxyLike` classes allow one to define the type parameter `Repr`, to further restrict the return type of the proxy. One could define:

```
class MySeqLikeClass[T] extends Seq[T] with SeqProxyLike[T, MySeqLikeClass[T]] {
  protected[this] def newBuilder: mutable.Builder[T, MySeqLikeClass[T]] = ???
  def seq: Seq[T] = ???
  def self: MySeqLikeClass[T] = ???
}
```

Filling in only the above methods allows `MySeqLikeClass[T]` to be used exactly like a `Seq` AND return `MySeqLikeClass[T]` on all functions rather than a `Seq[T]` as `SeqProxy[T]` would.

Comment: Does this forward all methods even if I used it to create a forwarding-list? I could image its only for methods defined in SeqLike.

Comment: Yes, however there are only 4 methods in `List` that `SeqProxyLike` doesn't cover, `::`, `:::`, `reverse_:::`, and `mapConserve`.

Answer (score 2):

You could take the easy route and extend [`SeqProxy`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.SeqProxy):

```
import collection.SeqProxy

class ForwardingList[T](val self: List[T]) extends SeqProxy[T]

val xs = List(2,3,5,7,11,13)
val fs = new ForwardingList(xs)

println(fs.size)    // 6
println(fs(0))      // 2
fs foreach println  // 2,...,13
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question fully, just gives one example way of forwarding to the collection `Seq`